# Waiting for durable entity value to change

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

```
[FunctionName("SetDurable")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SetDurable(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "SetDurable/{durable}")] HttpRequestMessage req,
        [DurableClient] IDurableEntityClient client,
        string durable)
        {
           var entityId = new EntityId(DurableEntitiesNames.BirSessionIdentificatorEntity, DurableEntitiesNames.BirSessionIdentificatorKey);
           await client.SignalEntityAsync<IBirSessionIdentificator>(entityId, identificator => identificator.Set(durable) );
           //await Task.Delay(2000);
           EntityStateResponse<JObject> stateResponse = await client.ReadEntityStateAsync<JObject>(entityId);
           var setResult = stateResponse.EntityState.ToObject<BirSessionIdentificatorResult>().Sid;
           return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK){Content = new StringContent($"{setResult}")};
    }
```

In Azure Functions v3 when i try to set the value of durable entity and then immediately try to read this value, it returns old value instead of the new value.
But when i uncomment the Task.Delay and make it wait 2 seconds after setting the value of durable entity i get correct value while trying to read it.

Is there any way to await the completion of durable entity value setting operation?

Comment: Hi, just checking, did my answer help you out? If so, please [mark it as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) or feel free to ask for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to await the completion of durable entity value setting operation?

No, at least not when using `SignalEntityAsync`. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-bindings#entity-client-usage):

> It's important to understand that the "signals" sent from the client are simply enqueued, to be processed asynchronously at a later time. In particular, the `SignalEntityAsync` usually returns before the entity even starts the operation, and it is not possible to get back the return value or observe exceptions. **If stronger guarantees are required (e.g. for workflows), orchestrator functions should be used, which can wait for entity operations to complete, and can process return values and observe exceptions.**

The bold part is your way out: you can use a [proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-dotnet-entities#accessing-entities-through-interfaces) from within an orchestration to get access to the durable entity. That way you can await the operation. An example:

```cs
[FunctionName("DeleteCounter")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DeleteCounter(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "delete", Route = "Counter/{entityKey}")] HttpRequestMessage req,
    [DurableClient] IDurableEntityClient client,
    string entityKey)
{
    var entityId = new EntityId("Counter", entityKey);
    await client.SignalEntityAsync<ICounter>(entityId, proxy => proxy.Delete());    
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
}
```

here we await the call of the Delete method on the entity.

Comment: Either I'm reading the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.webjobs.extensions.durabletask.idurableentityclient.signalentityasync?view=azure-dotnet#microsoft-azure-webjobs-extensions-durabletask-idurableentityclient-signalentityasync-1(microsoft-azure-webjobs-extensions-durabletask-entityid-system-action((-0)))) wrong. But it clearly states that `SignalEntityAsync` returns *A task that completes when the message has been reliably enqueued.*

Comment: @smoksnes indeed the operation is *enqueued*, not *executed* or *completed*. That state is reached once the operation is dequeued and actually performed.

Comment: @smoksnes as stated in my answer: *It's important to understand that the "signals" sent from the client are simply enqueued, **to be processed asynchronously at a later time**. *

Comment: Well, yes, I totally agree. That part i correct. However I suggest you change *That way you can await the operation* to something like *That way you can await the operation to be queued*. And similarly *here we await the call of the Delete method on the entity* to *here we await the Delete method to be queued*.

Comment: Otherwise you should use `CallEntityAsync` - *Calls an operation on an entity and waits for it to complete* - [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.webjobs.extensions.durabletask.idurableorchestrationcontext.callentityasync?view=azure-dotnet) - that way you actually await the operation, which `SignalEntityAsync` doesn't. Then you will need a `IDurableOrchestrationContext` instead of `IDurableEntityClient `